# SharePoint - programmatically add list items and set ID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need to create list items in sharepoint and also set the ID field too.  However I get an error when trying to do this as it's read only.  Is there a way I can set the ID column value when programmatically creating items in a sharepoint list?

As a side note the reason I need to do this is because I need to add items to two sharepoint lists where the second uses the id column of the first as a lookup.

thanks

Kamran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already mentioned, the ID of a list item is marked as read only. And I think there is no way to work around that.

I think the easiest solution would be to add a new column to the second list which uses the first ID column for lookup. Then the items in list one and two still have two different IDs but you can reference them by the second column in list two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on similar project I chose to stick with the OOB Id field only just customized the New Edit and Display forms with Custom forms for both the lists and also deleted all list items and Reindexed both lists and this worked for me as the Custom New form Created list items in both lists and the view and display forms loaded the listItem on the basis of listItem Id field only.
The need to do this was that some fields should be editable when an item is created and some not so separated them in these two lists and managed the permissions respectively.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the distant past with ReserveListItemId where you can increase the next list item ID pointer before creating one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj862551(v=office.15)

The documentation here is pretty worthless, but I'm pretty sure this is your starting point.